# TypeError: google.visualization.arrayToDataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy this [example](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#image_multicolor_bar_chart).

The example has this definition:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['a', 14],
['b', 47],
['c', 80],
['d', 55],
['e', 16],
['f', 90],
['g', 29],
['h', 23],
['i', 58],
['j', 48]
// Treat first row as data as well.
  ], true);
```

I have replaced the first parameter with my variable `buckets` which is also an array of length-2 arrays. I'm getting the following error which makes no sense:

```
TypeError: google.visualization.arrayToDataTable is not a function
```

Even if `buckets` is malformed(which I don't think it is) how could that change the identity of arrayToDataTable? It's still a function!

Comment: Dynamic loading should help https://developers.google.com/loader/#dynamic-loading

Answer (score 24):

I understand that this is a very late answer, but just in case anybody else comes across this question I'll post this here.
I had the same error, but then I checked out how Google Developers did it on their jsfiddle.

Replace this:

```
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

With this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload= 
{'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':
['corechart']}]}"></script>
```

And then delete this line:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

And of course, make sure that you run it on a server.

Comment: @abagh0703:- What if i am using this:-`google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'annotationchart', 'calendar', 'gantt', 'gauge', 'map', 'orgchart', 'sankey', 'timeline', 'treemap', 'wordtree'] });`. How to write.?

Comment: if i am using `google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'annotationchart', 'calendar', 'gantt', 'gauge', 'map', 'orgchart', 'sankey', 'timeline', 'treemap', 'wordtree'] });` instead of `google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});`?

Comment: @Sanjiv what happens if you try using the 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload= 
{'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':
['corechart', 'annotationchart', 'calendar', 'gantt', 'gauge', 'map', 'orgchart', 'sankey', 'timeline', 'treemap', 'wordtree']}]}"></script>` 
method instead of the `google.charts.load` method?

Comment: You make my day Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't loaded the Google Visualization API. Have you got this somewhere?

```
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['imagechart']});
</script>
```

FYI - I got this by clicking the *Edit HTML* button on the example page

Comment: Phil I do have that loaded at the top. The example works fine for me; I am getting that error when I replace the first parameter with my own `buckets`.